# Правильно ли составлена схема предложения?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Немцы все силы сосредоточили именно там, где будут переправляться наши войска.

[...], (где...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, правильно. Немцы все силы сосредоточили именно там -  главное, где будут ... - придаточное.